# Magento 2.3.4: Exception #0 Recoverable Error: Object of class Magento\Framework\App\State\Interceptor could not be converted to string

Tags: php, magento2.3.4, webserver

I am employing the code below to check what deployment mode server is on. This is throwing the error. Please point out the issue with the usage of the object `$this->_appState` to get the the mode. Thanks.

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem) {
    $this->_appState  = $appState->getMode();
    // Code to get the absolute path to the pub folder.
    $this->_pubPath = $fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::PUB)->getAbsolutePath();
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * getAllPagesJSContent() returns the custom JS contents to calling custom allpages.js.
 * This function checks if the deployment mode is production or not, and returns
 * pmm/custom/js/allpages.min.js or pmm/custom/js/allpages.js
 *
 * @param void
 * @return string file contents or empty
 */
public function getAllPagesJSContent() {
    echo $this->_appState;
    // Check current environment. If it is the production retrieve the allpages.min.js file.
    if ($this->_appState == "production") {
        echo "Hello from production 1";
        if (($custom_js_file_contents = $this->get_custom_js_file_contents('allpages.min.js')) !== FALSE) {
            return $custom_js_file_contents;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code if it helps!

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\State $_appState **/
protected $_appState;

public function __construct(
    ......
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState
    ......
)
{
    $this->_appState = $appState;
}

public function getCurrentMode() {

    // Check current environment
    if ($this->_appState->getMode() == \Magento\Framework\App\State::MODE_PRODUCTION) {
        die("Current Mode is Production");      
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I did the same thing finally leaving me wondering why `$this->_appState  = $appState->getMode();` shouldn't work. What makes it different from `$this->_appState->getMode()`?

Comment: Not sure about it, maybe issue with the object conversion to string.